# How to differentiate between two lines in an image

Tags: java, math, image-processing, machine-learning

I have two different types of images which looks like below.

**Image 1**
[image: Image 1]

**Image 2**
[image: Image 2]

I am working on a classification problem using machine learning in Java (OpenCV, ImageJ and Weka). My region of interest is marked in the red box. As you can see from images, visually both regions of interest are different. I am trying to find a method using which I can pro-grammatically assure that both are different. I am trying to retrieve data from images for training set to classify them. Image 1 as Negative and Image 2 as Positive. I have 1000's different images which look similar like these but they are not identical.

I have coordinate points of all three lines. I have tried using mean, standard deviation, R square, sum of squared errors values for green line but the results were not consistent which makes machine learning results inconsistent.

I want to whether there is parameter/s which is consistent and can give me a numeric value to differentiate two images from each other. I want to know whether there is a mathematical approach to solve this problem. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:
Both images are of size 496*1024. No, lines can be of any length

Comment: Can you describe more what makes 2 images different? Do they have to cross each other? Does one of the lines be much longer than the others? Sth. different?

Comment: @RenéScheibe No, they don't cross each other. Usually, green line is longer than other two lines in the images but the length of green line varies from image to image (not consistent)

Comment: if you are familiar with neural nets you can use them to identify your classes.

Comment: @xro7 I know the basics of neural nets but never used in big projects. Can you please point in the right direction?

Comment: This is the best material to enter the world of neural nets http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/index.html but it takes some time.The author uses NN and classifies images of handwritten digits. The basic idea is to get the pixels of your images  and train your neural network in order to learn your different image classes. Of course there are more advanced ways to do that using convolutional NN but first you need to understand the basics of simple NN.

Comment: Generally this approach takes time and might be an overkill for your case but there are a lot of libraries that will enable you to use a NN in a few lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate projection profiles, which sum up the foreground pixels in either the x- or y-direction. Preferably you create a projection profile in the x-direction of the green line, so for every x-position of the green line you count the number of foreground pixels in the y-direction.

As a result, you can create a histogram H=(h_1,...,h_i,...,h_width), where h_i indicates the number of foreground pixels in the y-direction at position i of the green line. In case of image 2, you should see two peaks in H indicating the drop of the green line.

Comment: I will try this approach and will let you know if this worked. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of pixels for each of the 3 colors. It should provide a good approximation of the line lengths. Then compare them.

Comment: This is not necessarily a very robust approximation, especially as the line length can be influenced by the curvature and other deviations (small peaks).

Comment: @Rene Thank you for your reply. I have tried this approach but it didn't give me good results.